# How to write this code to be used in python?

Tags: python-3.x

We are given this example in our textbook. However, the example is in Java (I think, I am not familiar with java) and our assignment is to be done in python. Is there a way to translate the example into python?

```
BinarySearch(numbers, numbersSize, key) {
   mid = 0
   low = 0
   high = numbersSize - 1

   while (high >= low) {
      mid = (high + low) / 2
      if (numbers[mid] < key) {
         low = mid + 1
      }
      else if (numbers[mid] > key) {
         high = mid - 1
      }
      else {
         return mid
      }
   }

   return -1 // not found
}
main() {
   numbers = { 2, 4, 7, 10, 11, 32, 45, 87 }
   NUMBERS_SIZE = 8
   i = 0
   key = 0
   keyIndex = 0

   print("NUMBERS: ")
   for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS_SIZE; ++i) {
      print(numbers[i] + " ")
   }
   printLine()

   print("Enter a value: ")
   key = getIntFromUser()

   keyIndex = BinarySearch(numbers, NUMBERS_SIZE, key)

   if (keyIndex == -1) {
      printLine(key + " was not found.")
   }
   else {
      printLine("Found " + key + " at index " + keyIndex + ".")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Isn't In Java!

Here Is The Py Code !

```
def binary_search(item_list,item):
    first = 0
    last = len(item_list)-1
    found = False
    while(first<=last and not found):
        mid = (first + last)//2
        if item_list[mid] == item :
            found = True
        else:
            if item < item_list[mid]:
                last = mid - 1
            else:
                first = mid + 1 
    return found

print(binary_search([1,2,3,5,8], 6))
print(binary_search([1,2,3,5,8], 5))
```

I Hope It Help and You're From Which Grade ??

Peace✌!